# Replacing Will_paginate with Kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate, kaminari

I am replacing will_paginate with Kaminari and large part of my application uses .paginate method with multiple conditions.

```
@posts = Post.published.paginate(:order => 'published_at desc, id',
                                  :joins => :comments,
                                  :conditions => conditions,
                                  :group => "posts.id",
                                  :per_page => 10, 
                                  :page => params[:page])
```

I am looking for quickest way and the most efficient way to replace such code with kaminari.

Rather then

```
@posts = Post.published.paginate.order('published_at desc').....page().per()
```